# Tomcat JDBC pool connections all stuck at Socket Read, and no new connection is created

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 7 application hosted on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk, and a MySQL 5.5 database hosted on Amazon RDS. The database server serves only one Tomcat application and has max connection limit set to 10,000.

However strange things are happening to the DB connections after few hours of uptime.

MySQL server reports that only 3 connections were created by Tomcat JDBC connection pool, they were all "sleeping" (example output):

```
| 228 | root     | ip-10-240-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:33270 | xxxxx | Sleep   |   13 |       | NULL             |
```

Tomcat thread dump suggested that all 3 connections are reading (blocking) from network IO sockets:

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
        - locked <0x00000000bc349cc0> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3036)
```

Because there are only 3 DB connections in connection pool and they are all stuck on IO read, Tomcat refuses to serve any more HTTP requests that require DB data.

Tomcat JDBC pool settings have assigned:

```
maxActive="500"
maxIdle="100"
minIdle="50"
initialSize="50"
maxWait="15000"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="120000"
logAbandoned="true"
testOnBorrow="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
validationQuery="select 1"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

Still unsure why all of 3 DB connections got stuck at network IO read, however given the configuration above, I would expect Tomcat to create additional connections when all existing connections are busy.

I have 8 other Beanstalk applications using identical setup, however only this particular application has such strange pooling behaviour and network IO problem.

What do you suggest?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested on http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31353, you might have a unsafe thread problem.

Comment: Thank you. Following the bug report and other online discussions, I added "socketTimeout=30000" to MySQL JDBC connection string, remove connection eviction settings and remove connection abandoning settings, the problem is finally resolved.